# Action with set of fixed parameters in url and a set of optional parameters either from post or from querystring

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, query-string, model-binding

In my route collection I have

routes.MapRoute(
  "Recalculate",
  "{siteLanguage}/Formula.mvc/relcalculate/{identifierString}/{formulaId}/{wratio}/{customRecalcString}",
  new { controller = "Formula", action = "Recalculate", wratio = "", customRecalcString = "" }
 );

The action it maps to is

```
public ActionResult Recalculate(string identifierString, int formulaId, string wratio, string customRecalcString, string targetQuantity, int? targetUnit)
```

As you can see there are severa paremeters that are not in the route description.
These are optional parameters.
When I come in with a POST, the values I put in my form are properly mapped to these parameters.
When I enter with a GET however, the variables are added to the querystring:

```
/en/Formula.mvc/relcalculate/493133---GREEN%20TILE%20TEST%20PLAQUE---SPECTROSYSTEM/2972591?targetQuantity=1&targetUnit=1
```

But when arriving at the action, the parameters and the querystring are empty...

Any ideas?

**Edit**
It seems the querystring just dissapeared halfway.
Altered OP to reflect this
**Edit2**
After further investigation it appears that once again it comes down to asp.net-mvc's encoding algorithms that seem to fail (or is it me?) 
If I fill in the URL in the browser address bar, it works perfectly.
Only when the string is used as an action="" attribute value the querystring dissapears.
If I'm not mistaking the '&' of the querystring should be encoded.

Why isn't Url.RouteUrl() doing this?
Why is Url.Encode() giving me all kinds of bull?
How can I encode only the querystring part without encoding the values?
**Edit3**
I surrounded the action with Html.Encode() which I should have done from the start off course. Now the page validates again.. but to no avail.
**Edit4**
Found it!
Basically it's this HTML that's failing

```
<form action="/en/Formula.mvc/relcalculate/493133---GREEN%20TILE%20TEST%20PLAQUE---SPECTROSYSTEM/2972591?targetQuantity=50&amp;targetUnit=0" method="get">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="noPrint" value="Remove RFU" />
    </div>
</form>
```

As soon as I change the method of the form from get to post, everything works out fine.
That were 2 hours well spent!
**Update**
In response to comment:
With regard of non-disclosure paranoia I will leave out some stuff, but here's the gist of the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReadyForUse.aspx.cs" Inherits="CommonProject.Web.Shared.Views.ProductMix.ReadyForUse" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="headerContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <link href="<%=PathHelper.CssUrl("productMix.css")%>" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>    
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <%string action = Url.RouteUrl("Recalculate",
          new { 
              siteLanguage = ViewData.Model.SiteLanguage.Iso6391[0],
              identifierString = ColorService.GetIdentifierString(ViewData.Model.ActiveColor),
              formulaId = ViewData.Model.ActiveFormula.FormulaId,
              targetQuantity = FormulaService.ParseQuantityFromVolumeString(ViewData.Model.TargetVolume),
              targetUnit = FormulaService.ParseUnitFromVolumeString(ViewData.Model.TargetVolume).Id,
              wratio = ViewData.Model.Wratio.ToString(),
              customRecalcString = ProductMixService.GetCustomRecalcValuesString(ViewData.Model.GaugesStructure)
          });
      string removeAction = Url.RouteUrl("Recalculate",
          new { 
              siteLanguage = ViewData.Model.SiteLanguage.Iso6391[0],
              identifierString = ColorService.GetIdentifierString(ViewData.Model.ActiveColor),
              formulaId = ViewData.Model.ActiveFormula.FormulaId,
              targetQuantity = FormulaService.ParseQuantityFromVolumeString(ViewData.Model.TargetVolume).ToString(),
              targetUnit = FormulaService.ParseUnitFromVolumeString(ViewData.Model.TargetVolume).Id,
          });
    %> 
    <snip/>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                <div>   
                    <a href="<%=Html.Encode(action)%>" alt="test">thisWorks</a>
                    <form action="<%=Html.Encode(action)%>" method="get">
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" value="thisDoesnt" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="50%">
                <div>                
                    <a href="<%=Html.Encode(removeAction)%>" alt="test">thisWorks</a>
                    <form action="<%=Html.Encode(removeAction)%>" method="get">
                        <div>                                        
                            <input type="submit" value="thisDoesnt" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="javaScriptPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <script src="/Content/scripts/effects.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=PathHelper.JsUrl("productMix.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

I tend to define the action urls at the start of the page so I can find it easely and it doesn't litter my page. Also, I know the table is blasphemy, but with the time I've wasted yesterday it will have to do for the time being. I'll have to pay the programmer's tax in a later cycle.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't understand. Surrounding identifierString with "Html.Encode()" helped or not (it should)?

Comment: It didn't. It helped out validating my page, but not solve the issue. See edit 4 for the solution. Well the way it worked. I still don't get why it wasn't working before...

Comment: Can you show your .asp/cx markup where form gets rendered? There might be case when similar situation appears and you can't just switch to 'POST'.

Answer (score 0):

I just created [sample application](http://drop.io/pggacis) =>

controller:

```
 public class FooController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Bar
            (string fizz1, int fizz2, string fizz3, string fizz4, 
             string fizz5, int? fizz6)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4} | {5}", 
                fizz1, fizz2, fizz3, fizz4, fizz5, fizz6.HasValue ? fizz6.Value.ToString():""));

            return Content(sb.ToString());
        }

    }
```

global.asax:

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    "Default",                                              // Route name
            //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            //);

            routes.MapRoute(
                    "FooBar",
                    "{siteLanguage}/bar/{fizz1}/{fizz2}/{fizz3}/{fizz4}",
                    new { controller = "Foo", action = "Bar", fizz3 = "", fizz4 = "" }
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Results:

> http://localhost:4038/en/bar/fizz1/2?fizz5=val&fizz6=1

returns

> fizz1 | 2 | | | val | 1

Problem seems to be elsewhere. Are there any filters/model binders doing something?

Comment: I think I found the root cause. Edit2 in the OP tries to explain more.

Comment: No modelbinders here except the on-board ones.